# rosserial_python on Pandaboard - Fuerte

Tags: ros, ros-fuerte, rosserial-python, pandaboard

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hey,

I was trying to get rosserial_python to work on my Pandaboard (Ubuntu Oneiric server edition), which has ros Fuerte installed on it, but it seems to miss some kind of module. Here is the error I am getting:

```
  File "/home/panda/ros/rosserial/rosserial_python/nodes/serial_node.py", line 40, in <module>
    from rosserial_python import SerialClient
  File "/home/panda/ros/rosserial/rosserial_python/src/rosserial_python/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from SerialClient import *
  File "/home/panda/ros/rosserial/rosserial_python/src/rosserial_python/SerialClient.py", line 42, in <module>
    from serial import *
ImportError: No module named serial
```

I'm sure it is an easy error, but I couldn't find the solution.

Any idea what I'm missing? Thanks in advance.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/33040/rosserial_python-on-pandaboard---fuerte/) by [Hansg91](https://answers.ros.org/users/1621/hansg91/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1909 on 2012-05-01

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You need the pySerial package. You can install it by running the following command:

```
sudo apt-get install python-serial
```

A good way to install system dependencies for ROS packages is the `rosdep` command. To see how to install `rosdep` take a look at http://answers.ros.org/question/32875/rosdep-command-not-found. You can then run something like:

```
rosdep install rosserial
```

Unfortunately, `rosserial_python` does not list `python-serial` as a dependency, so the second option won't work right now. I'll report this bug to the developers shortly.

---

Originally posted by [piyushk](https://answers.ros.org/users/1770/piyushk/) with karma: 2871 on 2012-05-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Hansg91](https://answers.ros.org/users/1621/hansg91/) on 2012-05-01**:
Ah I guess I was missing that one, thanks again :) I did indeed try rosdep install but it claimed all dependencies were met.

**Comment by [piyushk](https://answers.ros.org/users/1770/piyushk/) on 2012-05-01**:
Yeah, it was unlucky the dependency was not listed. This bug has been reported: https://kforge.ros.org/rosserial/trac/ticket/59

**Comment by [ulrichard](https://answers.ros.org/users/1774/ulrichard/) on 2012-07-06**:
I have a similar issue on my raspberry pi with debian squeeze / ros fuerte.

```
$ rosdep install -a --os=debian:squeeze
#All required rosdeps installed successfully
$ rosdep install rosserial --os=debian:squeeze
    
ERROR: Rosdep cannot find all required resources to answer your q
```